# This site is practically just a Mini-Modding site

Tags: discussion, branding

This isn't a question site, this is where people bash you over one small capital word or one small spelling mistake and as their excuse: "wer net absin"

This "Question" site is horrible at answering questions. If you're one of those immature kids who bashed at me, stay out.

Answer (score 23):

"Minimodding" as you call it is an integral part of this website's operations. Yes, we make it possible for anybody on the internet to edit anybody's posts, just like Wikipedia does. One of the tenets is that questions and the answers thereof help more than just you, so people are encouraged to make them as good as they can be.

We understand this formula doesn't work for everyone, so we'll understand if you do not wish to contribute any further. If you want a place where people can't edit others' posts, may I suggest just about any other website on the internet? :)

Answer (score 10):

Arqade is all about collaborative editing and peer-review, as badp has covered. We're all people just like you who came here with a question or two, and we stuck around to help make the internet a better place by providing wiki-style Q&A.

We edit posts to make them clearer and to remove swearing or bad formatting (such as over-capitalisation as you mention) so that they look nice when other people see them.

That's all. There's no malice here, no 'bashing' - and if there actually was hate speech, bullying or otherwise pointed attacks against a user or group, you just have to flag the post and walk away. Behaviour such as that is not tolerated and dealt with harshly should it occur.

Look, I think you're overreacting a little after the shock of having your posts edited for the first time, it happens. If you haven't left already and actually read this after that initial shock reaction has passed, I suggest you take a quick look at our [Tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) page, as it explains what we're about, why and when we edit posts, and a bunch of other useful info.

In any case, I sincerely wish you the best of luck with your future endeavors, and hope you have a Happy New Year :-)